# Editing YAML file using python not giving exact output

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I'm editing YAML file but it isn't giving the exact output as I want. There is a difference between indentation and square brackets.

```
import yaml

add_info = {'network':
        {'version': 2,
         'renderer': 'networkd',
         'ethernets':
             {'enx1':
                {
                    'addresses': ['193.254.1.8/24'],
                    'nameservers': {'addresses':
                                    ['193.254.1.5, 8.8.8.8']},
                    'routes': [{
                        'to': '193.254.1.0/24',
                        'via': '193.254.1.5'
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }

with open('/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-test.yaml', 'w') as f:
    data1 = yaml.dump(add_info, f, sort_keys=False)
    print(data1)
```

Current Output I'm getting from above code.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx1:
      addresses:
      - 193.254.1.8/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 193.254.1.5, 8.8.8.8
      routes:
      - to: 193.254.1.0/24
        via: 193.254.1.5
```

This is the exact Output I want:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx1:
      addresses:
      - 193.254.1.6/24
      nameservers:
          addresses: [193.254.1.5, 8.8.8.8]
      routes:
          - to: 193.254.1.0/24
            via: 193.254.1.5
```

Comment: i dont think that's possible since the indentation style is not consistent in your expected output (see the lists under your `addresses:` and `routes:`).

Comment: and the two `addresses:` lists are using different notation (`-` style vs. `[ ... ]` style).

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_? There is no bash involved in the question. Also, why do you say in the title that you want to _edit_  a file, but everything you do is to _create_ a file?

Comment: @user1934428 all I've to do is to edit a config file which is already available in the directory, currently I'm doing it for testing purpose

Comment: @pynexj that is what I want my 2nd addresses field, I want them in a list ([...])instead of "-".

Comment: But the `'w'` in the `open` statement actually overwrites what has been there. This is not suitable for "editing".

Comment: @roXx , i guess you have to write your own `yaml.dump()`.

Comment: @roXx typo: you want your python list to have the same two elements as your YAML:  `['193.254.1.5', '8.8.8.8']` as opposed to your current one list element `['193.254.1.5, 8.8.8.8']`

Comment: @pynex there is no problem with combining block vs flow style in YAML it is just difficult (but not impossible) to achieve in PyYAML.

Comment: @roXx You should not put data after the triple backquotes in your posts, it won't show in the rendering as it is used to define the type of content in your code block.

Comment: @Anthon , right but the lib cannot guess when you want block style and when for flow style.

Comment: @pynexj Indeed you need to have some rule/pattern or an explicit marking of datastructure elements. In the OPs case the lib could infer that a single string element in a list that contains comma+space needs to be split and written in flow style, but that is IMO less clear than explicit marking as in my answer (and that also allows use of those elements in the normal way of accessing a list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using PyYAML. It only supports a subset of YAML 1.1 (which was superseded in 2009)
and doesn't give you much fine control.

Start with what you want to get and see how well that round-trips in `ruamel.yaml`:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx1:
      addresses:
      - 193.254.1.6/24
      nameservers:
          addresses: [193.254.1.5, 8.8.8.8]
      routes:
          - to: 193.254.1.0/24
            via: 193.254.1.5
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
# print(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx1:
      addresses:
      - 193.254.1.6/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [193.254.1.5, 8.8.8.8]
      routes:
      - to: 193.254.1.0/24
        via: 193.254.1.5
```

You do have control seperately over indentation of mappings and sequences, but
your sequences are not indented consistently: the sequence that is the value
for `addresses` has an indent of 2 with an offset for the sequence indicator (`-`)
within that of 0, and for the sequence that is the value of routes is indented 6 with an offset of 4;
your mappings are not indented consistently either (using 2 and 4 positions). `ruamel.yaml`
doesn't give you that fine control.

If you want to start with your datastructure you need to provide the valued for `addresses` not as list
of a single string with embedded comma, but as the subclass of a list that `ruamel.yaml` uses (you
could find which by inspecting `data` after loading) and mark it to be represented as flow style:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def FS(*args):
    seq = ruamel.yaml.CommentedSeq(args)
    seq.fa.set_flow_style()
    return seq

add_info = {'network':
        {'version': 2,
         'renderer': 'networkd',
         'ethernets':
             {'enx1':
                {
                    'addresses': ['193.254.1.8/24'],
                    'nameservers': {'addresses':
                                    FS('193.254.1.5', '8.8.8.8')},  # <- changed
                    'routes': [{
                        'to': '193.254.1.0/24',
                        'via': '193.254.1.5'
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(add_info, sys.stdout)
```

which also gives:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx1:
      addresses:
      - 193.254.1.8/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [193.254.1.5, 8.8.8.8]
      routes:
      - to: 193.254.1.0/24
        via: 193.254.1.5
```